Conditionally Hide Show Fields On A SharePoint List Form
I am creating a SharePoint list in which I have list 'Invoice/Receipts'.
I am doing conditional formula so that when the 'Cost Category' column value 'Travel' or 'Allowances' is selected, 'Invoice/Receipts' shows up when adding new item.

And what's the question? :)

Need to know the formula. It is a choice column. This is the example currently saved on the Microsoft community. =if([$Category] == 'Product Management', 'true', 'false') but it is just if one condition if that is fulfilled. Mine is that either 'Travel' or 'Allowances' is selected the 'Invoice/Receipts' field should show up.

If 'Cost Category' column is a single selection choice column in the SharePoint list,
Use conditional formula like below for 'Invoice/Receipts' column:
=if([$CostCategory] == 'Travel' || [$CostCategory] == 'Allowances', 'true', 'false')

Where [$CostCategory] is an internal name of your column in SharePoint list in this format: [$InternalNameOfColumn].
You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?
Documentation: Show or hide columns in a SharePoint list or library form

Note: Choice columns with multiple selections are not supported in SharePoint conditional formulas.

Thank you so much. It worked.

Great, glad it worked for you! Keep using this platform to ask any questions related to SharePoint.

Can you please accept my above response as an Answer as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thanks!
